# What is the correct time format for random Forest?

Tags: r, time, format, random-forest, posixct

I've created a **randomForest** model to predict the working state of a machine. One of the variables used for prediction is "time". I've converted the timestamp of my dataset (POSIXct format) to **ITime-format**, so that I only have the daytime without the date.

```
kwpower <- kwpower %>% mutate(time = as.ITime(timestamp, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

If I run the model, which works fine, and use the varImpPlot, it tells me, that "time" is the most important variable. I wonder if this can really be true and if the ITime-format is the right time-format to use in randomForest? What is the correct/best time-format when using randomForest?

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should not use "time" attribute with RF classifier. Decision Trees prefer attributes having a lot of unique values due to gini index or information gain. Therefore, a DT will always point out such an attribute as being most important. Try training the RF model without "time" attribute. Also, if you want to use time series analysis, RF is not the way to go about it. Look into smoothing, exponential smoothing, ARIMA, LSTM RNN etc for it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't really leave out the time aspect so I suggest I have to change my method... In addition to your suggestions (ARIMA etc.), would you reccomend the approach of using support vector machine for my case?

Comment: Refer to-  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/time-series-forecast-using-svm